# ffmpeg get frame time stamp

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, video-capture

I am trying to record a webcam video using ffmpeg. I have a logitech c922 Pro Stream Webcam. This is the command that I use:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video1 out.mp4
```

My application requires me to get the exact timestamp for every frame. While I could use my knowledge of the framerate and frame number to add the required interval to the start time, I am afraid that this might not be completely accurate.

Firstly, I have noticed that while recording, the console seems to initially display a far higher fps than the one I have set:

```
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  177 fps= 85 q=-1.0 Lsize=     502kB time=00:00:02.91 bitrate=1410.8kbits/s dup=144 drop=0
```

Also, I think that ffmpeg drops frames in between sometimes.

However, my videos seem to have the correct number of frames so I think that the fps value displayed could instead be referring to the encoding/ decoding speed. I am not sure about frame dropping.

I would be happy of you could let me know what you think, or suggest an alternative so that I can timestamp my frames accurately. Thanks!

Edit:

I have understood that frame rate is correlated to ambient light which can lead to high duplication in frames. I am currently recording on windows and have set frame rate as the priority in logitech gaming software. However there is still the occasional drop in frame or duplication. Does this affect time stamp of the frames? Or can I extrapolate from the start time?

Comment: Your source isn't supplying 60 fps, it's closer to 12 fps. ffmpeg is duplicating the other 48 fps. It is possible to discover the wallclock timestamp, but not advised to use that value for storage. Lt me see how to offload it before muxing.

Comment: Is the duplication a result of my incorrect command? The camera itself supports recording @60 fps. I could also switch to windows which has support for the logitech software.